# code after window.alert not executing when additional dialog boxes prevented

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

In firefox 38 I noticed that If I activate the browsers anti-popup feature, that it stops executing the code on the lines that follows a call to `window.alert()` or `window.confirm()`

For example, given code:

```js
var cb = document.querySelector("input");
cb.onclick = function(){
    console.log("before alert");
    window.alert("foo");
    console.log("after alert");
};
```

```html
<center><input type=checkbox></center>
```

If you click the checkbox a few times, with less than 3 seconds between each click, then in the popup you'll have a choice to "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs". Activate that. After you do, you'll see that the console.log after the alert stops getting executed.

**Is this an intended firefox behavior? Where is it documented?**

Chrome doesn't behave this way - it still executes the code after the `window.alert()` line.

**Edit** - I found a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633154 . It seems that in some versions they throw an NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE exception if the alert is suppressed, but some versions they don't and it's silent.

Comment: My Firefox is 44 and i'm getting both console logs normally also after checking prevent alert checkbox in alert popup, try to update your Firefox to latest one

Comment: @Armen you're right, v44 behaves normal. v38, 40, and I think also 42 behaved in this odd manner.

Comment: If it some important alert/confirmation messages you can instead default one use some ready made popups there is plenty of them: http://defunkt.io/facebox/ or http://fancybox.net/  or choose one of this https://codegeekz.com/jquery-modal-plugins/ etc.. and implement `ok` `cancel` buttons with `callbacks` inside it, so it will behaves under different browsers in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find any mentions of such strange alert behaviour. HTML5 spec. does say only general:

> ... the user agent might give the user the option to ignore all alerts ...

I would suggest to wrap alert into try/catch block to make it behave "standard": https://jsfiddle.net/zvtam8ur/6/

```js
function myAlert(message) {
  try {
    window.alert(message);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("alert error!");
  }
}

var cb = document.querySelector("input");
cb.onclick = function(){
  console.log("before alert");
 myAlert("foo");
  console.log("after alert");
};
```

Comment: This works on some versions. Sometimes firefox throws an exception when the alert is suppressed, but in other versions it fails silently.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in Firefox and Google chrome.

There is no such functionality in there.

Not even with confirm (example is given here)-

```js
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    console.log("before alert");
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    console.log("after alert");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a confirm box and check your console log.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

And surely normal alert is not also allow it in Firefox and Chrome-

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log("before alert");
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    console.log("after alert");
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display an alert box and check the console log.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

And my testing result in Firefox and Chrome is given in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw_ZG739xqg).

And to see more clearly, please change the speed of the video like this-

[image]

Hope, u have your complete answer.

Comment: Thanks, in newer firefox versions they changed the behavior.